# Will Kalista's ultimate extend Blitzcrank's Rocket Grab?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm wondering if this is working since Blitz + Thresh's pull was removed.

If Blitz pulls an enemy, Kalista timely used his ultimate, the grab landed and

Blitzcrank clicked just a few seconds after the call, will the grabbed enemy

land where Blitzcrank launched himself?

Comment: Was the Blitz + Thresh pull just removed this patch? I remember Kalista + Blitz happened in last week's NA LCS on 5.2, if that helps.

Comment: My first guess would be the pulled enemy will end up where Blitz was when he cast the ability. There are some weird interactions I've seen with Kalista's ult though, so I can't be 100% sure about it

Comment: Unsure on latest patch, but Kalista + Blitz + Thresh is a thing. You can also Kalista + TP to bring your soulbound with you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's called the Balista.
Here's a vid for reference